# Why can I not pass a numeric template parameter to my templated function?

Tags: c++, c++-templates

I have a custom class encapsulating a `std::tuple` ("MyTuple") and another class implementing a custom interface for a `std::tuple` ("MyInterface"). I need this separate interface in the code base, the code below is simplified.

Since elements of `std::tuple` need to be accessed with the key as template parameter, the interface's functions have a numeric template parameter `size_t Key` which is then given to `std::get` for the tuple for example.

This interface works fine, but not when calling it from another templated function which passes a numeric parameter as "key":

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template <typename... Types>
class MyInterface {
  public:
    MyInterface(const std::tuple<Types...>& tuple) : tuple(tuple) {}

    template <size_t Key>
    std::string getString() {
      return std::to_string(std::get<Key>(tuple));
    }
  private:
    const std::tuple<Types...>& tuple;
};

template <typename... Types>
class MyTuple {

  public:
    MyTuple(Types... values) : value(std::tuple<Types...>(values...)) {}

    template <size_t Key>
    std::string asString() {
      MyInterface<Types...> interface(value);
      return interface.getString<Key>(); // here I get the compiler error
    }

  private:
    std::tuple<Types...> value;
};

int main() {
  MyInterface<int, float, long> interface(std::tuple<int, float, long>(7, 3.3, 40));
  std::cout << interface.getString<0>() << std::endl; // this works fine

  MyTuple<int, float, long> tuple(7, 3.3, 40);
  std::cout << tuple.asString<0>() << std::endl;
}
```

Complete output of g++:

```
templated_function_parameter_pack.cpp: In member function ‘std::__cxx11::string MyTuple<Types>::asString()’:
templated_function_parameter_pack.cpp:28:39: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
       return interface.getString<Key>(); // here I get the compiler error
                                       ^
templated_function_parameter_pack.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::__cxx11::string MyTuple<Types>::asString() [with long unsigned int Key = 0; Types = {int, float, long int}; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
templated_function_parameter_pack.cpp:40:34:   required from here
templated_function_parameter_pack.cpp:28:33: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘long unsigned int’ to binary ‘operator<’
       return interface.getString<Key>(); // here I get the compiler error
```

Why is not valid syntax to call `interface.getString<Key>()` inside `MyTuple::asString<size_t Key>`?

Comment: You also forgot to include <tuple> and other essential headers

Comment: ... and `<string>`

Comment: Please post all the error messages. Anyway, `return interface.template getString<Key>();`

Comment: Thank you for comments, I updated the code example (forgot some things, sorry), and added the complete output of g++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to call a template method of an instance, you need to write this:

```
return interface.template getString<Key>();
```

You'll find every details of why in this answer: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)